# Google maps: how to find if user is near our office

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

How to point the area near office and find if the user near the office. If employee is near office or inside office building then he is able to login to our crm.

Please send me links how to accomplish that. Thanks.

Comment: check if this helps you: https://github.com/nzcage/googlemap

Answer (score 0):

Well @JohnDoe if you are using javascript you can use https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

refer to [samples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/) its a good start

from geolocation services you can get lat lng of user and then calculate distance from your office using office lat lng

However S.O is not a place for asking such abstract questions. First you try something out , then if you get stuck , you post that piece of code

Comment: How to get lat and lng?

Comment: help me to find the link please